# html <a> tag is clickable but linking functionality not work in all areas

Tags: html, css

i have  a list of `<li>` tag and each `<li>` has `<a>` child and each `<a>`  has an `<img>` tag and a text inside of it.
my problem is linking functionality not works in whole area of `<a>` tag like corners and near `<img>` and text but in in whole area `<a>` tag in clickable.

Here is a [Link](http://maaha.ir/Menu/) and [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6dpNp/)

Comment: It works fine in FF22

Comment: what browser? I see nothing strange

Comment: -1, This question is unlikely to help future visitors. Please make it more generic if you don't want it to be put on hold.

Comment: reduce the  `border-radius: 3px;`

Comment: @artSx in firefox and chrome latest versions

Comment: clicking near `<img>` about 1px doesn't work

Comment: @Jeremy if you can not reproduce the problem it doesn't mean that problem doesn't exist

Comment: @SoheilGh I'd be sorry if I said that, but I didn't. Your question isn't helpful. Period.

Comment: @Jeremy see this [image](http://i.cubeupload.com/qaxsRS.png) . click on every point of black line does not change the url

Comment: @Jeremy try 1px left of line . it doesn't go to google.com in this area . i try this several times

Comment: Hm. There do seem to be some pixels where you can click but it doesn't work. It feels random though, and then it works the second time I click.

Comment: problem occurs because of `li:active` . i delete it and it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

deleting `li:active` solves my problem . because before and after clicking the pointer is in 2 different tag in this areas. (`<a>` before and `<img>` after)

```
.menu li:active
{
margin-right: 8px;
margin-left: 4px;
margin-top:4px;
}
```

here is an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6dpNp/3/)

Comment: If that is indeed the problem, then maybe you could use a background image rather than an `img` element in the `a` element. Then you won't have to give up the "depress" effect. http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/6dpNp/2/

Comment: Tnx @MrLister . the problem with `background-image` is that i want the image overflow from `<a>` tag. i delete the `li:active` and problem solved